# How can I insert data in a SQL-database with python and variable tablename, rows and values?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want something like this. But the following does not work
The tablename is saved in e, the name of the row in i[0] and the value in k.

"INSERT INTO ? (?) VALUES(?)" (e, i[0], k)

Comment: You can't use placeholders for table and column names. You have to use string formatting functions for that, then you can use the result in a prepared statement.

Comment: "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES(?)".format(i[e], i[0]), (k) I tried it this way but it didn't work